# Android and GCM

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I need to write a simple chat for Android. I want to use the fuel, but I can not figure out how to make the settings. What should be done on the server (php) and the client (android)?

Comment: sorry, way to broad  a question for here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for android:
create settings model:

```
public class SettingsModel {
    public String login;
    public String token;
    .....
}
```

add another class for manipulating with settings:

```
public class SettingsService {

    private static String KEY = "mySettingsKeyCustomString";
    private static Context mContext;

    public static SettingsModel settings;

    public SettingsService(){
        mContext = MyApplication.getLastGrabContext(); // MyApplication extends Application
        settings = getSettings();
    }

    public static void saveSettings(){
        if(settings == null){
            settings = new SettingsModel();
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext
                .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonSettings = gson.toJson(settings);
        editor.putString("settings", jsonSettings );
        editor.commit();
        settings = getSettings();
    }


    public static SettingsModel getSettings() {
        SharedPreferences editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences(KEY,
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try{
            String jsonSettings = editor.getString("settings","settings");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            settings = gson.fromJson(jsonSettings, SettingsModel.class);
        }catch (Exception e){
            settings = new SettingsModel();
        }

        return settings;
    }

}
```

and now for example in Application class init settings in onCreate:

```
new SettingsService();
```

now you are free to call from anywhere to get your settings like:

```
String login = SettingsService.settings.login;
```

you can update settings with:

```
SettingsService.settings.login = "new login";
SettingsService.saveSettings();
```

make sure you have in your gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```